# Problem installing a CMake package on local environment in CentOS 7

Tags: python, cmake, centos

So, I'm an absolute 0 when it comes to linux and right now I've been battling with installing a package that I need for some data analysis.

The package is [spt3g](https://github.com/CMB-S4/spt3g_software) and I'm trying to install it in a CentOS 7 system. I don't have root access so I'm running everything on a miniconda environment. My CMake version is 3.17.0, GCC is 7.3.0, Boost is 1.73 & Python is 3.8.2.

When I try to do the installation process (i.e cd spt3g, mkdir build, cd build, cmake .. , make) there is an error at 25% :

```
spt3g/core/src/G3Timestream.cxx:11:10: fatal error: FLAC/stream_encoder.h: No such file or directory

include FLAC/stream_encoder.h
```

Edit: I manage to reach 91% of installation by using the following versions: CMake: 3.17.2, GCC: 4.8.5, Boost: 1.53.0 & Python: 3.8.2.
 The error I get in this case is the following:

```
spt3g/maps/src/FlatSkyMap.cxx: In function ‘boost::python::api::object flatskymap_getitem_2d(const FlatSkyMap&, boost::python::tuple)’:
spt3g/maps/src/FlatSkyMap.cxx:771:18: error: ‘slice’ is not a member of ‘bp’
  if (bp::extract<bp::slice>(coords[0]).check()) {
                  ^
spt3g/maps/src/FlatSkyMap.cxx:771:18: error: ‘slice’ is not a member of ‘bp’
spt3g_software-master/maps/src/FlatSkyMap.cxx:771:27: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  if (bp::extract<bp::slice>(coords[0]).check()) {
                           ^
spt3g/maps/src/FlatSkyMap.cxx:773:3: error: ‘slice’ is not a member of ‘bp’
   bp::slice yslice = bp::extract<bp::slice>(coords[0]);
   ^
spt3g/maps/src/FlatSkyMap.cxx:773:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘yslice’
   bp::slice yslice = bp::extract<bp::slice>(coords[0]);
             ^
spt3g/maps/src/FlatSkyMap.cxx:774:3: error: ‘slice’ is not a member of ‘bp’
   bp::slice xslice = bp::extract<bp::slice>(coords[1]);
   ^
spt3g/maps/src/FlatSkyMap.cxx:774:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘xslice’
   bp::slice xslice = bp::extract<bp::slice>(coords[1]);
             ^
spt3g/maps/src/FlatSkyMap.cxx:779:7: error: ‘yslice’ was not declared in this scope
   if (yslice.start().ptr() != Py_None)
       ^
spt3g/maps/src/FlatSkyMap.cxx:783:7: error: ‘yslice’ was not declared in this scope
   if (yslice.stop().ptr() != Py_None)
       ^
spt3g/maps/src/FlatSkyMap.cxx:787:7: error: ‘yslice’ was not declared in this scope
   if (yslice.step().ptr() != Py_None)
       ^
spt3g/maps/src/FlatSkyMap.cxx:789:7: error: ‘xslice’ was not declared in this scope
   if (xslice.start().ptr() != Py_None)
       ^
spt3g/maps/src/FlatSkyMap.cxx:793:7: error: ‘xslice’ was not declared in this scope
   if (xslice.stop().ptr() != Py_None)
       ^
spt3g/maps/src/FlatSkyMap.cxx:797:7: error: ‘xslice’ was not declared in this scope
   if (xslice.step().ptr() != Py_None)
       ^
At global scope:
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-self-assign-overloaded" [-Werror]
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-constant-conversion" [-Werror]
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-deprecated-register" [-Werror]
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unknown-warning-option" [-Werror]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [maps/CMakeFiles/maps.dir/src/FlatSkyMap.cxx.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [maps/CMakeFiles/maps.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Finally, I know the package works since I have it installed on my laptop but can't run the analysis here because I don't have a cooling system for my CPU (the analysis script uses all of it)

Any help for installing this package from scratch would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you install the dependencies for this package (as seen on the site you linked): `yum install cmake netcdf-devel boost-devel flac-devel fftw-devel gsl-devel` ??

Comment: @squareskittles yes. All of those dependencies are installed.